# Letting $z = x+ iy$, prove that $\left|x\right| +\left|y\right| \le \sqrt{2}\left|z\right|$

Tags: complex-numbers

From Basic Complex Anyalsis 1.3 #16

Letting $z = x+ iy$, prove that $\left|x\right| +\left|y\right| \le \sqrt{2}\left|z\right|$

I know that $\left|z\right|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. I have attempted starting to start working with the left side using the triangle inequality to no avail. Just not sure where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$0 \le (|x|-|y|)^2 = |x|^2-2|x||y| + |y|^2 $, hence $2|x||y| \le |x|^2+|y|^2$.

$(|x|+|y|)^2 = |x|^2+2|x||y| + |y|^2 \le 2(|x|^2+|y|^2)$, taking square roots gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides, we have
$$
x^2 + 2|xy| + y^2 < 2|z|^2  \iff x^2 + 2|xy| +y^2 < 2(x^2 + y^2),
$$
which is AM-GM.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use trigonometry $$|\cos \theta| + | \sin\theta| \leq \sqrt{2}$$ (two trig identities are needed to show this)